# Will memcpy correctly copy an array allocated with mkl_malloc?

Tags: c, intel-mkl

I'm allocating an array with `mkl_malloc` with a `64` alignment, and I need to make a copy of it. But I don't understand how aligning works. Does `mkl_malloc` just add padding at the end so that the total size of the array is a multiple of 64 bytes? Or will there also be padding between array elements?

Will code like the example below copy all of `a` into `b`, or only part of it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mkl.h>

int main() {
    double *a = mkl_malloc(10 * sizeof(double), 64);

    // is this enough memory to include a?
    double *b = malloc(10 * sizeof(double));

    // will this copy all of a?
    memcpy(b, a, 10 * sizeof(double));

    mkl_free(a);
    free(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Or will there also be padding between array elements?* - think, how can it even do it? It is returning you a pointer to `void`, it doesn't have any notion of "elements". And it is aligning the *start* of array, no padding in the end is required.

Comment: @EugeneSh. .. and even if there were, the C Standard explicitly defines that no padding *between* array elements shall occur.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks, can you put it as an answer?

Comment: Nah.. too lazy.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'd UV your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45331632/will-memcpy-correctly-copy-an-array-allocated-with-mkl-malloc#comment77625272_45331632), but I guess I am T.L. too.   ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example `memcpy(b, a, 10 * sizeof(double));` will work correctly.

Alignment applies to the *start address*, not to the size of the reserved memory block.